Loop to assign mixins to classes in scss
I want to assign several @mixins to classes with the same name, something like:
@each $herramienta in $listaHerramientas {
    .#{$herramienta} {
        @include #{$herramienta};
    }
}

The compiler throws the error Expected identifier, which seems to mean the @include does not admit variables. Is that right? Is there a way to avoid writing all classes one by one?

Instead of using @include, you can use @use to import mixins from another module and then include them dynamically.

In _mixins.scss, define your mixins like this:
    // _mixins.scss
    @mixin tool1 {
        // Your mixin styles for tool1
    }

    @mixin tool2 {
      // Your mixin styles for tool2
    }
    // ... and so on

In your main SCSS file (e.g., styles.scss), use @use to import the _mixins.scss file:
    // styles.scss
    @use 'mixins' as *; // Import all mixins from _mixins.scss

    @each $herramienta in $listaHerramientas {
        .#{$herramienta} {
             @include #{$herramienta}; // Include the mixin dynamically
       }
  }

Make sure both files (_mixins.scss and styles.scss) are in the same directory.


Well, that's exactly what I was doing and where the problem appeared. Having your mixins in a separate scss doc doesnt change the fact that scss does not compile variables in the @include.
